# Video Streaming not works on Google TV in an Android Application in 3.1

Tags: android, eclipse, google-tv

I am new to Android development and i have been asked to create an App in Android for Google TV that will show a user some live channels and will play a live stream when user selects one. I have managed to do so and its working fine. I used **MediaPlayer** to play my streams and  Channels play properly MOST of the time.

I have overridden **setOnErrorListener** to know if something is wrong. This catches most of the errors if any and i **finish()** the player activity after showing proper message.

Initially i show a **loading** message in a progress bar to the user while the stream is getting ready. i **dismiss()** the progress bar and **start()** the MediaPlayer after **setOnPreparedListener** listener is called.

I am unable to run the rtsp:// stream. it hangs after playing a little.

1. the Progress Bar remains there and the app is kind of stuck.
2. Pressing **Back** button on D-Pad does not work either
3. I receive no errors in **setOnErrorListener** listener at all
4. I cannot close the application as whenever i click on my App's icon, it opens the same black "Loading" player page..

**Android 3.1 (API 12) is used and all stream URLs start with rtsp://**

Following are the xml/java file's code:

**NOTE: I copied and altered the VideoPlayer.java & video_player.xml files [MediaPlayer_Demo example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html).**

**video_player.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Erroneous VideoPlayer.Java is as follows:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnErrorListener {

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Bundle extras;
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/**
 * 
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

    this.extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

private void playVideo() {
    doCleanUp();
    try {

        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
                true);

        // Check Internet Status
        if (!AppStatus.isInternetAvailable(this)) {
            showErrorToUser(getResources().getText(R.string.about_net)
                    .toString(),
                    "Internet connection is not available or Wi-Fi is not enabled.");
        } else {
            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            String videoStreamUrl = extras.getString("streamUrl");

            if (videoStreamUrl != null) {
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoStreamUrl);
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                showErrorToUser("Invalid Stream URI",
                        "The Video's URI is not valid. Please provide correct URI.");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        errorOccured();
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height
                + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    playVideo();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

    this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    errorOccured();
    return true;
}

private void errorOccured() {
    UserMessage
            .showPopup(
                    this,
                    "Channel not available",
                    "We are sorry for the inconvenience but this channel is not available right now. Please try later.");
}

private void showErrorToUser(String title, String message) {
    // Hide Progress Bar
    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();

    UserMessage.showPopup(this, title, message);
    }
}
```

I created **UserMessage** & **AppStatus** classes for making development fast, I learnt them from SO. These classes are fine and, according to my knowledge & understanding, are not causing any errors. I am providing them just to share and have better understanding of **VideoPlayer.java**.

These classes are as follows just to share so anyother person could use them:

**UserMessage.Java**

```
public class UserMessage {
public static void showPopup(final Activity activity, String title, String message) {

    View view = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.about, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(message);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }).show();
    }
}
```

**AppStatus.Java**

```
public class AppStatus {

public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)  {               

    ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = mgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() && netInfo.isAvailable());
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as i am almost at the end of finishing my app.

Thanks for reading and thinking even if you could not answer me.

Comment: What video type is the stream?

Comment: well i am not sure of the stream type ... but all the URLs i play start with rtsp://.. i saw somewhere that Android supports this format

Comment: It should be supported, but it's not common for an app to use.  Flash uses it mostly.  First - see if you can play the video on a phone or tablet.  If that works, send me your URL and I'll take a look.  google-tv-fishtank-team (at) googlegroups dot com

Comment: ok i will send the specific link to you when it gives me the problem as i have many links and i am not sure which one causes the issue. Thank you very much

Comment: @Les ... i have sent the email with a URL at google-tv-fishtank-team (at) googlegroups dot com a few days ago .. can u please check it as this is the only reason for not putting my app on Market..

Comment: Just found it, it was stuck in review.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your problem is that while we do support RTSP, it's done in software, not hardware.  When you need to rescale it, that too, is done in in software.  When you present a fairly large size, like yours, and it needs to be scaled, it under runs. Giving the behavior your seeing.  MP4's are a better solution.

Comment: Thank u very much for ur effort.. I appreciate it very much.. I now understand the reason for this problem... But can u be more specific about MP4?? as it can also have Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264) .. which our RTSP streams have .. so an MP4 stream with same codec may not run again.... We use Wowze Server for streaming .. can u guide me to the best Codec/stream type that a Wowza server can produce for Android devices??

Comment: Wowza says it streams H.264.  http://www.wowza.com/media-server  That should work quite nicely.  If I were building a system from scratch, I'd be using HLS.  Wowza says it support it.

Comment: Well our RTSP stream is actually H.264 ... but u would have seen that it does not work at all.. i will talk to our streaming responsible person about HLS .. we have waited so long ... so i think we should give it a try too.. Thank u very much

Comment: i m bothering u again .. but i dont know anyone else to ask this. I tried running HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) but it does not run too... u can check by replacing the RTSP by HTTP and adding "/playlist.m3u8" to the same url i already have sent to u.

Comment: I'll look again next week - there will also be an update shortly that should help in this area.  What kind of box are you using to develop?

Comment: I dont know what do u mean by "What kind of box are you using to develop?".. but we have Logitech Revue™ With Google TV™ (http://www.logitech.com/en-us/smartTV/revue) which i use to test my app/videos.

Comment: I tested the HLS stream today and it was playing .. though i could not play it for long time... but it plays now ... is this because our Logitech device is updated??